# Wildfly server with hostname

Tags: wildfly, hostname

I have tried to use the hostname in no-IP, and I used port 443 for my server, I also add hostname into hosts file on MAC OS, so I only can access hostname via localhost, but when I access from the internet, it didn't redirect to my hostname, can some help me?

Comment: Anyone can help me? I was stuck here a long time

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "**public**" interface is configured to listen on the loopback address of 127.0.0.1. (ie localhost).

If you want to bind to **all** available IP addresses, you should start Wildfly with a specific binding address, using -b:

```
./bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: yes, I also did it, I can access the server through IP with a specific port, but can't access to the server through hostname

Answer (score 0):

Update a interface inet-address with 0.0.0.0 like below and restart a server.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```